# Возможно ли заполнить массив $_GET не из формы(а скажем из командной строки)?

Tags: php

Возможно ли заполнить суперглобальный гет массив без использования сервера(т.е не из http форм), а скажем через командную строку? Если в консоли написать например php name.php?..

Comment: вы лучше скажите, что именно вы делаете, что у вас такая идея появилась. Если у вас скрипт работает в двух режимах, серверном и консольном, то разделите логику получения входных данных для этих режимов. В одном случае берите из get в другом из командной строки. не надо костыли делать какие-то.

Comment: пишу CGI в учебных целях, в  RFC 3875 написано, что через переменные окружения нужно передать только информацию для PUT и GET. Я передаю и GET тоже. Мне интересно, как правильно нужно заполнять  $_GET

Comment: GET - это ассоциативный массив, мы можете его заполнить и передавать основному скрипту, используя, к примеру, значения из файла, либо из консольных параметров.